# Is Lewis Carroll correct in his suggestion on some abbreviations?

Tags: abbreviations, apostrophe

The following is quoted from the preface to [Sylvie and Bruno Concluded](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/211/sylvie-and-bruno-concluded/4639/preface/) by Lewis Carroll:

> Other critics have objected to certain innovations in spelling, such as ‘ca’n’t’, ‘wo’n’t’, ‘traveler’. In reply, I can only plead my firm conviction that the popular usage is wrong. As to ‘ca’n’t’, it will not be disputed that, in all other words ending in ‘n’t’, these letters are an abbreviation of ‘not’; and it is surely absurd to suppose that, in this solitary instance, ‘not’ is represented by ‘’t’! In fact ‘can’t’ is the proper abbreviation for ‘can it’, just as ‘is’t’ is for ‘is it’. Again, in ‘wo’n’t’, the first apostrophe is needed, because the word ‘would’ is here abridged into ‘wo’: but I hold it proper to spell ‘don’t’ with only one apostrophe, because the word ‘do’ is here complete. As to such words as ‘traveler’, I hold the correct principle to be, to double the consonant when the accent falls on that syllable; otherwise to leave it single. This rule is observed in most cases (e.g. we double the ‘r’ in ‘preferred’, but leave it single in ‘offered’), so that I am only extending, to other cases, an existing rule. I admit, however, that I do not spell ‘parallel’, as the rule would have it; but here we are constrained, by the etymology, to insert the double ‘l’.

I have discussed with my English teacher about writing "cannot" as "ca'n't" but she disagrees as she insisted only one apostrophe is allowed in each word. Does Lewis Carroll's advice on the abbreviation make sense?

Comment: What about rock-'n'-roll, then?

Comment: Lewis Carrol died in 1898, and our orthography has evolved and become more conventionalized since then. Whether logical or not, we've settled on using one apostrophe in these words.

Comment: Bear in mind that Lewis Carroll was English, and was no doubt aware of (and perhaps fond of) a number of English dialects.  I have heard (probably exaggerated) English dialects where "cannot" is pronounced (roughly) "kay-n't".  I would suspect that Carroll was favoring that pronunciation with his "ca'n't" spelling.

Comment: I ca'n't understand why Carroll never uses the abbreviation _wi'n't_ for "will not," given that he seems to believe that, in the strictly logical world of truly correct English, _wo'n't_ always and only stands for "would not." I also wonder whether the contraction _wouldn't_ had somehow slipped his mind at the point where he says, "Again, in ‘wo’n’t’, the first apostrophe is needed, because the word ‘would’ is here abridged into ‘wo’."

Comment: I've seen people say similar things about "shan't" vs "sha'n't" (short for "shall not"), often quite vociferously. But the range of contractions allowed in English is based on custom: it's not just an arbitrary thing where you can shorten any word you feel like in any place in a sentence, so it seems likely that spelling would be based on custom too.

Comment: Stuart is right; usage drives acceptability. It's very rare to encounter a contraction having more than one apostrophe, but forecastle has 2- and 3-apostrophe variants:  fo'c'sle/fo'c's'le.  The two-apostrophe variant obviously represents the omitted letters inadequately if slavish devotion to 'the rules' is demanded, but the general tendency in English over time is to simplify, shy away from diacritical confetti (compare minimal punctuation). // Spelling variants _are_ often available, often with regional preferences; dictionaries show standard variants, again often with regional preferences.

Answer (score 5):

Even Carroll admits, by the word 'innovations' that these spellings are not the usual ones. He had the same rights to change English orthography as any of us have; the method is to use (and explain as necessary) your preferred form, and hope that it catches on. Carroll/Dodgson had certain advantages that most of us do not; he was an Oxford professor, an acknowledged expert in playing with words, and the author of a book that was so popular that Queen Victoria asked him to dedicate his next to her. (The story goes that she was disappointed when it was a learned treatise on mathematics.) Despite all these, none of his innovations seem to have caught on, with the possible exception of *traveler* which I understand is sometimes used in the United States.

Comment: Single L *traveler* predates his writings. See for example "The traveler is struck with the magnitude..of the stream"
J. Hall, [Statistics of West](https://books.google.com/books/about/Statistics_of_the_West.html?id=JVAVAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1#v=onepage&q=Traveler&f=false), 1836. The author is American.

Comment: Using non-standard spellings often has the avoidable downsides of losing marks in essays and quizzes, losing the respect of readers, and generally undignifying the language.

Answer (score 1):

'traveler' IS the official spelling in American English. Likewise with other verbs (and other words) ending in 'l' when a suffix is added (-er, -ed, -ing, -ous, etc) where British English doubles the 'l'.  E.g. leveled, canceling, modeled, marvelous.  There are some curious cases which seem to go against the general pattern, e.g. British fulfil/fulfilment (but note: fulfilling) vs US fulfill/fulfillment (fulfilling).

Comment: The trouble with statements including such constraints as 'official way of doing things in American / British / Australian / Indian ... English' is that 'official' (etc) in this sense means 'agreed to or arranged by people in positions of authority' ... and there are no legitimate  governing bodies _attempting_ (think of the situation with French) to regulate the language. What happens if you're a Brit in NY or an American in Wigan? What happens halfway across the Atlantic? What's 'official' then? And do quotes get respelled? 'The _usual_ spellings among ...' rings truer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple apostrophes are allowed -Forecastle is
also written fo'c'sle, after sailors' /ˈfəʊks(ə)l/.

Can't and won't are correct and ca'n't and wo'n't (or should that be wil'n't) are wrong.

The OED has the history of "cannot/can't" and at no stage in the evolution does a double apostrophe appear.

**Can't** appears 1600 when it is more or less accepted as there is no real fixed orthography but in the 1800 it was considered "non-standard" and generally used to indicate dialect or in lower-class speech.

(Other versions caant, and caan't also appear after 1900)

The US produced

1. 1800s cayn't, kain't
2. 1800s–caint, cain't
3. 1900s keint

The negation however, is always the same **"n't"** with no other apostrophes.

The dictum in English is **"When enough people are wrong, they are right."**

> Does Lewis Carroll's advice on the abbreviation make sense?

No, not really. He ignored the dictum. A fatal mistake but understandable in a mathematician and thus concerned only with things falling into logical patterns.

The words themselves are two words and, had he really thought about it he would have written the verb, left a space, and then added "n't" **can n't**